# DAX Calculated Column is not working correctly

Tags: dax, grouping, calculated-columns, ssas-tabular, summarize

I have the following table with over 10K records in my SSAS Tabular model

Client Episodes Monthly Rollup:

[image]

I need to create a Calculated Column in DAX - [DaysGroups].

This Column should assign days intervals - 0-90 Days, 91-180 Days, 181-270 Days, 270+ Days, based on the highest [LengthOfStayToDate] value,
for each [ClientWHID], where [DischargeDate] = 2050-12-31 and [EpisodeStatus] = "ACTIVE".

In the example above - there are 2 ClientWHIDs - 30636, 37623

If [ClientWHID] = 30636, [DischargeDate] = 2050-12-31 and [EpisodeStatus] = "ACTIVE", the highest [LengthOfStayToDate] value = 335. This means, my Calculated Column [DaysGroups] should assign "270+ Days" interval for all records where ClientWHID = 30636.

If [ClientWHID] = 37623, [DischargeDate] = 2050-12-31 and [EpisodeStatus] = "ACTIVE", then the highest value for that Client = 2 (only one value in this example). This means, my Calculated Column [DaysGroups] should have all records "0-90 Days" for [ClientWHID] = 37623.

I have the following DAX code, but it assigns ALL ClientWHIDs with "270+ Days" interval

```
  VAR ActiveRecords =
        CALCULATETABLE (
         'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup',
           FILTER (
            'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup',
            'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup'[EpisodeStatus] = "ACTIVE"
         && 'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup'[DischargeDate] = DATE ( 2050, 12, 31 )
            
                   )
                        )

  VAR MaxLOSByClient =
      SUMMARIZE (
         ActiveRecords,
         'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup'[ClientWHID],
           "MaxLOS", MAXX (
              'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup',
              'Client Episodes Monthly Rollup'[LengthOfStayToDate]
                          )
                  )

   VAR MaxLOS = MAXX ( MaxLOSByClient, [MaxLOS] )
   RETURN

    SWITCH (
       TRUE (),
       MaxLOS >= 0
        && MaxLOS <= 90, "0-90",
       MaxLOS >= 91
        && MaxLOS <= 180, "91-180",
       MaxLOS >= 181
        && MaxLOS <= 270, "181-270",
       MaxLOS > 270, "270+",
      BLANK ()
         )
```

The resulting Calculated Column [DaysGroups] assigns my ALL clients to 270+ interval
See below:
[image]

Please - HELP !